# Redirect my domain name to a sub url

Tags: wordpress

I have a domain name with GoDaddy and I want it to auto forward traffic to another URL.

For example:

I want `www.mydomain.com` to auto-forward / redirect to `www.mydomain.com/gooo`

How do I configure this? I have tried several different methods (forwarding / redirecting etc), but haven't successfully managed to get this working.

this is `.htaccess` for folder site

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9] 
{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9] 
{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You can use .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file out this line:

```
RewriteRule ^www.mydomain.com/ /www.mydomain.com/gooo [L,R=301]
```

Comment: or please explain what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I edited my question. I want www.mydomain.com to auto-forward / redirect to www.mydomain.com/gooo